# Probability of getting heads on an even numbered flip

Tags: probability

What's the probability of getting heads on an even-numbered flip? What I would think is that getting heads on the second, fourth, etc. flip remains $1/2$.

Comment: Assuming that each flip is independent and the coin is fair, then indeed the probability of getting heads on an even-numbered flip (or any flip, for that matter), is $\frac12$.

Comment: I believe the question is asking for the probability that the *first* head occurs on an even-numbered flip.  That will be a bit less than 1/2 because the probability for it occurring on an odd-numbered flip has a slight advantage.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That would be a sensible question, but that is not what the OP asked. It is not at all clear what the OP is trying to ask, and the question should be closed as "unclear what you are asking", but it's pretty arbitrary to guess that he's asking about the first occurrence of heads.